# Use an activation code to change a role

Tags: activation, content-restriction, subscription

Wonder if you can help me.
I'm making a website based on accounts and a subscription for content control. At the minute, the way activation of a paid account works, is the user buys a subscription via a separate website, and then goes to a form link, which sends the code that they've bought to an administrator who manually controls their content and sets a reminder to remove their subscription.

As you can expect, this is really tedious, especially for when we grow. Is there a really easy way to do this e.g on signup you enter a code which automatically does this and then disables after the predefined time, or you go to website.com/activation where you do a similar thing?

I've tried looking for a plugin but can't find one... Can someone please point me in the right direction? Ideally GUI based.

Thank you!
Miles

Comment: look up any membership plugin.

Comment: anything in particular rudtek? looking for something that uses the roles in wordpress as that's how the restriction works. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Providing suggestions to plugins is a bit of a no no here.  There are so many things that people like versus don't like, want vs need etc. It's better to research them and see if they have what you need, especially without me knowing the entirety of your project.  Doing a quick search will show 2 or 3 great options though!  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking atm. Ideally something with roles as that's how I've been doing it, another system means more config which is a pita... Thanks!